# Hoping for help to translate a thought experiment into R code, using randomization

Tags: r

I'm more experienced with R than many of my peers, yet it sometimes takes hours to move a novel-to-me concept into the code line, and usually a few more to get a successful output. I don't know how to describe this in R language, so I hope you can help me- either with sample code, or pointing me in the right direction.

I have c(X1,X2,X3,...Xn) for starting variable, a non-random numeric value.
I have c(Y1,Y2,Y3,...Yn) for change variable, a non-random numeric value denoting by how much to change X, give or take, and a value between 0-10.
I have c(Z1,Z2,Z3,...Zn) which is the min and max range of X.

What I want to observe is the random sampling of all numbers X, which have all randomly had corresponding Y variable subtracted or added to them. What I'm trying to ask in this problem, is how many times will I draw X values which are exactly the X values which I initially input as well as give or take only a low Y value.

For instance,

```
Exes<-c(135,462,579,222)
Whys<-c(1,3,3,2)
Zees<-c(c(115,155),c(450,474),c(510,648),c(200,244))
```

First iteration: X=c(135,562,579,222), second iteration: X=c(130,471,585,230)<- as you can see, X of second iteration has changed by (-5*Y1), (+3*Y2), (+2*Y3), and (+11*Y4)

What I want to output is a list of randomized X values which have changed by only a factor of their corresponding Y value, and always fall within the range of given Z values. Further, I want to examine how many times at least one- and only one- X value will be be significantly different from the corresponding,starting input X.

I feel like I'm not wording the question succinctly, but I also feel that this is why I've posted. I'm not trying to ask for hand-holding, but rather seeking advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood the question, do you want to reiterate the process numerous times? is it for the purpose of simulation?. Here is a start of a solution.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c(135,462,579,222)
y <- c(1,3,3,2)
z.lower <- c(115, 450, 510, 200)
z.upper <- c(155, 474, 648, 244)

temp.df <- data.frame(x, y, z.lower, z.upper)

df %>% 
  mutate(samp = sample(seq(-10, 10, 1), nrow(temp.df))) %>% ### Sample numbers between 0 and 10 
  mutate(new.val = x + samp * y) %>% ### Create new X 
  mutate(is.bound = new.val < z.upper & new.val > z.lower) ### Check that falls in bounds

    x y z.lower z.upper samp new.val is.bound
1 135 1     115     155  -10     125     TRUE
2 462 3     450     474   10     492    FALSE
3 579 3     510     648    8     603     TRUE
4 222 2     200     244    6     234     TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset, this is a possibility:

```
Exes<-c(135,462,579,222)
Whys<-c(1,3,3,2)
Zees<-c(c(115,155),c(450,474),c(510,648),c(200,244))

n = 10000
x_range_l <- split(Zees, rep(seq_len(length(Zees) / 2), each = 2))

mapply(function(y, x_range) sample(seq(from = x_range[1], to = x_range[2], by = y), size = n, replace = T),
       Whys, x_range_l)
```

Note that this option depends more on the `Zees` than the `Exes`. A more complete way to do it would be:

```
Exes<-c(135,462,579,222)
Whys<-c(1,3,3,2)
Why_Range <- c(20, 4, 13, 11)

x_range_l <- Map(function(x, y, rng) c(x - y * rng, x + y * rng), Exes, Whys, Why_Range)

n = 10000

mapply(function(y, x_range) sample(seq(from = x_range[1], to = x_range[2], by = y), size = n, replace = T),
       Whys, x_range_l)
```